# How do get data from console.table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a test demo with console.table. As same bellow :

```
 console.table(table.row(this).data());
```

Ok, I see at console from Devtool GoogleChorme with content

```
Object
    AREA_ID: "A0002"
    EDIT_BY: "user 1"
    EDIT_DATE: "2014-11-05T00:00:00"
    FLAG: true
    LOCATION_DES: "BD"
    LOCATION_ID: "L0005"
    LOCATION_NAME: "Bình Dương"
    __proto__: Object
```

And now, i want to get data of some column and show , i.e column `LOCATION_NAME,LOCATION_DES...etc`. Give me some advice about this .Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.table` expects its argument to be an array of objects. Each element of the array becomes a row in the table and each property is a column. So use:

```
console.table([table.row(this).data()]);
```

to put the data into an array.